# Adaptive Text Spacing Navigation Bar SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

In my weather application I show the user's location in the `navigationBar` and the text needs to change based on what the user selects. When the user changes to a location with a shorter name than the one before it, the spacing is messed up. Anybody have an idea how to fix this? Thanks! Below is basically what my code is

[image: Here is what my app looks like]

[image: Notice the extra spacing between the edge of the screen and the text]

```
.navigationBarItems(leading:                                        
    Button(action: {
        
        showingLocation.toggle()
        impactMed.impactOccurred()
        
    }) {
        
        HStack() {
            Image(systemName: "location.fill")
                .font(.system(size: 20, weight: .bold))
                .foregroundColor(.alpineblue)
            
            if data.usingLocation == true {
                Text(self.userLocation)
                    .font(.custom("Avenir Next Bold", size: 20))
                    .foregroundColor(.alpineblue)
            }
            else {
                Text(data.locationName)
                    .font(.custom("Avenir Next Bold", size: 20))
                    .foregroundColor(.alpineblue)
            }
            
            
        }
    }.sheet(isPresented: $showingLocation) {
        LocationView(search: .constant("")).onDisappear(perform: data.loadData)
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing a .frame around your HStack of the Button label will hold the position. You'll want to make sure the frame width is wide enough to accommodate long city names however, otherwise you'll get text wrapping. Here's a quick mockup.

```
.navigationBarItems(leading: Button(action: {
            // do something
        }, label: {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "location.fill")
                if usingLocation {
                    Text("Edmonton, AB")
                } else {
                    Text("Sidney, BC")
                }
            }.frame(width: 200, alignment: .leading)
        }))
```